# Windows server 2008R2 routing with single NIC

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, routing

I'm trying to duplicate a Linux server configuration to a windows server 2008R2 box. Basicaly this linux server acts as a router, but it is doing its job with only 1 interface (1 NIC).

Here is the network configuration in place (I cannot change it) :

INTERNET <==> Router (local ip = 194.168.0.3) <==> linux Server (ip : 194.168.0.2).

The router is configured with a DMZ to 194.168.0.2, and only allow this IP to connect to internet (Cannot change this router configuration).

The linux server is configured with a default gateway to 194.168.0.3, with the option : "Act as router".

All other computer on the lan have this configuration (given by DHCP) :

IP range : 194.168.0.X MASK : 255.255.255.0 Default gateway : 194.168.0.2

And everything is working perfectly.

I'm trying to reproduce this way of routing with only one NIC from a windows server 2008R2, but it seems that you cannnot do it with only one NIC (all exemples I see are refering to 2 NIC with 2 different network).

Does someone have an idea how to achieved this in Windows server 2008R2 ?

Tx you for your help !

Fabian.

Answer (score 1):

Routing only happens between two (or more) different networks. If you have only one NIC, then either your have a local virtual segment or you're using another kind of interface to connect to another network.

Your network diagram doesn't make a whole lot of sense either: you should have (at least) two interface per router, not one.

Could it be that you actually have bridged your "internet router" and your "linux router" ? That would explain it, then. Also, what's the internal IP range looks like ? is it a routable IP range or do you need NAT ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable the Routing and Remote access service and then use that to configure the same settings as your linux box.

Comment: That's what I tried, but without succes ...

Comment: What results are you seeing?

Comment: The client machine cannot reach any outside IP adress.

Comment: Ping and tracert are not working either. When I look at the route table on the server i see the route definition (from : 0.0.0.0, submask : 0.0.0.0, destination : 194.168.0.3, correct NIC interface). It seems to be correct for me.